# Шаблонизатор сделай сам

Tags: php, html, javascript

Как сделать шаблон сайта? НЕ прописывать же каждую страницу в ручную. Просто сделать скелет на дивах, или нужно что то еще ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну, как правило, header, footer, т.е. шапка и подвал, их верстаешь и потом просто подключаешь с помощью include() во все файлы.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: инклудом? :) таким ещё кто-то занимается?

Comment: Занимаются, еще как! Взять допустим 1С Битрикс

Answer (score 3):

index.tpl:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   {TITLE}
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  {CONTENT}
 </body>
</html>
```

index.php:

```
<?
$title = 'Ололо';
$content = 'Тролололололо';
$html = str_replace(
array('{TITLE}','{CONTENT}'), 
array($title,$content), 
file_get_contents("./index.tpl"));
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: т.е. никакой заменяющей функции не надо?

Comment: str_replace(...) - а это что по вашему?
Просто из базы скриптом выводите информацию на страницу в переменную $content, затем срипт вставляет эту информацию туда где у вас в шаблоне указано {CONTENT}т.е в зависимости от переменной $contetn будет меняться контент вашего сайта, а дизайном будет служить всего 1 неизменяемый фаил tpl или какое вы там захотите дать ему разрешение.

Answer (score 1):

В свое время я делал примитивный шаблонизатор. Он выглядел так. Дизайнер-верстальщик вставлял метатеги (например, там где меню, он ставил ###menu###, там где блок новостей - ###news### и так далее). Понятно, что потом это можно обрабатывать обычной подменой, но это долго. Поэтому на perl был написан простенький скрипт, который брал шаблон и обычной заменой заменял ###menu### на `<?php include "menu.php" ?>` и так далее (вначале это была обычная замена, потом регулярка, которая и наличие файла проверяла, и теги левые отсекала). Позже даже параметры появились. Понятно, что не все  было через include. Например, тег ###copyright### заменяло просто нужным текстом.
Как результат - я занимался просто скриптами, для дизайнера была сделана простая форма заливки шаблонов, которая сразу же и php скрипт генерировала, и ошибки простые проверяла (просто html lint из cpan).